# How does optional binding function different from optional chaining?

Tags: swift, option-type

**EDITED:**

I am learning from a tutorial from Raywenderlich. My question is why do we use an optional binding ie `if let` what difference does it make? Why can't we use optional chaining—similar to Line A & B ?

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IconCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let icon = icons[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = icon.title // Line A
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = icon.subtitle // Line B

   if let imageView = cell.imageView, iconImage = icon.image { //Line C
      imageView.image = iconImage
    }
```

The instructor's explanation is :

*When we instance an icon we get a reference to the image based on a string...if for whatever reason that image isn't included in the bundle, renamed or deleted, then that icon may not have an image associated with it...and we have to use if let to make sure it is there.*

I still don't understand the difference.

Comment: binding lets you have an else statement. other than that, I don't see a major difference in your case

Comment: @Jared That's it? And if you don't put anything in the else statement, then is there any advantage to it?

Comment: also in the if let statement you no longer need to optional chain. So it is good for multiple lines of code. Other than that, there is not really an advantage

Comment: Honey, your edit removed a key piece of the code which fundamentally changes the question.  Without that code, @kennytm's answer makes no sense.  I have restored the code.

Comment: @vacawama Thank you. Apparently I got confused...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are thinking of

```
cell.imageView?.image = icon.image  // let's call this Line D
```

this is *not* equivalent to Line C.

If `cell.imageView` is not-nil, while `icon.image` is nil, line D will erase the original image of the imageView by setting it to nil.

However, in line C the condition will not be entered, thus keeping the original image even if `icon.image` is nil.

Line C is equivalent to

```
if let image = icon.image {
    cell.imageView?.image = image
}
```

I guess your professor just like to make it more explicit.

Comment: Won't line A,B also erase if they are nil? Why not write them with `if let` ? Also how can `cell.imageView` be not-nil? It's just about to be set here meaning it is definitely  `nil`

Comment: @Honey: (1) Yes they will. But you need to check the declaration of the icon type, they may be declared as `String` instead of `String?`. (2) If you are using storyboard, `cell.imageView` is assigned when you connect the cell to an image view in interface builder.

Comment: **1)** How is line C read? Is it read like: *If cell.imageView is not-nil while icon.image is also not-nil, then make imageView.image equal to icon.Image ie iconImage* ? **2)** why do we care about `cell.ImageView`'s value, I mean we want to set it to `icon.image`, regardless of it having a value or not. We only care if `icon.image` has a value or not. If it's nil, then we don't want to set it...

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Perhaps you should ask your instructor, I guess it is just personal style.